# How do I find all the classes that extend a class in an external library in visual studio or elsewhere?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Assuming I know what a particular base class is, does visual studio provide a way to list all the classes that extend that base class (as well as ones that extend those)? What about outside visual studio?

I'm specifically talking about base classes and extending classes both being from an external library.

For example, I'm trying to find a list of all the services that extend IServiceProvider. The base class is in the System namespace, and the classes that extend it are in a number of different namespaces.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? If vs2017, you just right click on the base class name or method in the class then choose FindAllReferences.

Comment: @machariadev I am using 2017, but doing that for IServiceProvider only lists the usages of IServiceProvider, no definitions of classes that extend it (such as IToolboxService). Is there some setting or plugin you are using that makes it behave differently for you?

Comment: Let me write up an answer with images of code definitions for a custom interface that I have. Is that okay?

Btw, am using vs2017, version 15.8.1

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL+F12` is probably your friend here.  You need to go to implementation.  So first, select the **base** class in the code file and press CTRL+F12.  So in the code sample below, select the class `Class1` in the definition or the definition for Class2.

Alternatively you can navigate definitions using the Object Browser `CTRL+W,J`.  This allows you to navigate all types loaded in the solution and other assemblies located in the `GAC`.

[image: ObjectBrowser]

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does offer a nice navigation to types which is slightly out of scope for this as it is a paid for tool.

[image: Find Usage Advanced]

Here is my sample code:

```
using System.Text;

namespace SOLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
    }

    public class Class3 : Class2
    {
    }

    public class MyEncoder1 : ASCIIEncoding
    {
    }

    public class MyEncoder2 : ASCIIEncoding
    {
    }

    public class MyEncoder3 : MyEncoder2
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This only lists the usages of a class when I use it on the class name in code (as in when I am using the type IServiceProvider), does it behave differently if you use it on the line that declares the class?

Comment: Updated answer to state you select the base class.  Added alternative where you can use the object browser additionally.  You could write some reflection based code - potentially it could run in Immediate Window to list out the types (I think!)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to clarify with screenshots and code. Ctrl + F12 does nothing, so I assume that is unique to your setup and does the same thing as Shift + F12 in mine (Find all References). Find all references only returned the usages of IServiceProvider in projects within my solution, rather than usages of it in external libraries. For additional clarification, I would expect IToolboxService (defined in System.Drawing.Design) if the search did what I want it to do. It looks like Resharper might do that if you checked Libraries in that screenshot you posted, can you confirm?